# Is there a climatic geo portal for every point in the world?

Tags: spatial-database, geoportal, climate

I'm looking for a geo portal or climate database that provides me with the daily climatic information like temperature, precipitation and humidity.

Forecast data is not of my interest.

I need information for every point with spatial resolution of not more that 3km.

Is there a service to provide me with this information?

The most important thing that I'm looking for is the continuity of the database.

The data in discrete stations is not enough for what I'm doing.

All I want is that when I query a point with latitude and longitude, the database or the geoportal gives me the temperature and rainfall rate of that point (no matter how accurate it is)

Comment: In addition to adding a bounty to this question you may want to consider re-writing it so that responders have a clearer idea of what you are looking for.

Comment: I added a sentence that tells what I want exactly

Comment: Please check out the answer by @A.R below (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49185/10799) Global Summary of the Day dataset is very informative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check climate in Canada according to different weather stations across the country http://www.climate.weatheroffice.gc.ca/climateData/canada_e.html

Comment: None of the answers was what I was looking for and perhaps this means that there is not such a database. Your answer was better in that I haven't seen this service before but I've seen all the other services before. Nevertheless, all of the answers was informative. Thank you all

Comment: Txs for the bounty! The problem with Canada is that they charge $150 an hour for collecting data...and it's a government service!!!

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of sites which provide varying ranges of climatic data at a broad range of spatial scales.

I often use [WorldClim](http://www.worldclim.org/) for global data and if I need higher resolution data for the USA I use data from the [PRISM group](http://www.prism.oregonstate.edu/). You could also look at [MODIS data](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/dataprod/index.php), which is very detailed, with many derivative datasets generated for ease of use.

I am not sure about the temporal resolution of these datasets, however, and you may struggle to get data on such a fine temporal resolution.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm working on these kinds of products and I was wondering if there is a geo web service to provide us with the processed information like by clicking the map or time evolving charts.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that you'll find a free database for climatic data, which contains literately every point in the world. I assume that even the most exact climate data is usually computed from models and already interpolated.

**For instance:** How do you plan to get exact climate information for locations somewhere in central Africa? In places where there has never been any historical weather observations? 
The [World Meterological organisation](http://worldweather.wmo.int/) lists on its site all official weather observation stations and you'll of course notice that there is a geographical bias to more developed countries. Of course there are a lot more smaller weather stations, but i doubt that there is some kind of global source, respectively data from which you could query your climatic information. I've found many sites on the net with weather data ([1](http://www.glisaclimate.org/search/data))([2](http://www.tutiempo.net/en/Climate/))([3](http://www.climatedata.eu/)), but all of them are incomplete or interpolated above time and space.
Sometimes local data can also be wrong/not validated or simply climatic outliers. In this [blog-post](http://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/comparing-worldclim-with-local-climate-data/) it is reported that Worldclim can even be more reliable in this case.

Stay with [Worldclim](http://www.worldclim.org/) and free available satellite data and set up an average value per year/timeframe to query values from. By merging and aggregating the worldclim raster layers you can easily query points all over the world via the point sampling tool. Maybe you can even save diskspace by converting it to other formats or importing to a geodatabase.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at: http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/uea-cru-ts-v3-10-01-historic-climate-database
Quote: "In January 2010, the University of East Anglia officially released the CRU-TS 3.0 Climate Database (See the official data release at http://badc.nerc.ac.uk/data/cru). This new version of database covers from 1901 to 2006*, globally at 0.5 degree spatial resolution on land areas. To help facilitate the use of this database in the CSI community using GIS software, we have converted the raw data into the ESRI ASCII raster format."
(the current version is 3.1 ) there are downloads (betwenn 60 and 160mb) for raster files for the following items:

```
cloud cover

diurnal temperature range

frost day frequency

precipitation

daily mean temperature

monthly average daily minimum temperature

monthly average daily maximum temperature

vapour pressure

wet day frequency
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the website climate.gov from NOAA (http://www.climate.gov/#dataServices).

These are the available datasets for the world: http://www.climate.gov/#dataServices/mapServices_global

Includes:

- Global Hourly Surface Data   (*)
- Global Hourly Summaries  (*)
- Global    Summary of the Day (GSOD)  (*)
- GHCN-Daily Data  (*)
- GHCN-D Monthly Summaries     (*)
- Historical Hurricane Tracks
- Marine Data
- Climate Data Record    (CDR)

(*)All these are station data and can be downloaded by station, country, or you can draw your polygon and extract the list of stations that fall inside.

It also includes data that you are not interested for the momment (Climate Prediction and Center Models/Forecasts)

Comment: +1 on the GSOD dataset! Quite useful for a lot of purposes.